# Cannot see WhatsApp pictures in folder

Tags: whatsapp, sd-card

I have all my photos on the SD card, and they're all in albums the folder WhatsApp inside Pictures.

But when I open my  photos in mob, only saved pictures, screenshots and Camera  get displayed. the pictures in WhatsApp is not displayed.

Thus none of my photos saved on SD card can be sent via WhatsApp. Please tell me how to resolve this.

Comment: Have you considered moving them to a different folder?

Answer (score 1):

Check in your SD card if there's a file named '.nomedia' .It prevents the phone from detecting photos. If it's there, delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the downloaded whatsapp images are available in whatsapp folder.. You can view it by using your file manager app called Files.. If its there and still not showing , then switch your photos to different folder and check it

Answer (score 0):

if there are a lot of images, wait a little cause reading speed on whatsapp folder is a lot slower than normal... In my case, my wpp images folder have around 25k pictures and when i open images folder it shows empty but if i wait the images starts showing... Sometimes i have to close folder and open again